# Há como limitar o números de caracteres de um crypt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografia, md5

Preciso encriptar alguns chaves de banco de dados para decriptar futuramente, porém todos as menssagens geradas precisam ter o mesmo tamanho. O md5 tem as mensagens geradas do mesmo tamanho, porém não dá para traduzir devolta(E não é criptografia, e sim message digest). Tentei usar o `simple-decrypt`, porém as mensagens geradas são de tamanhos diferentes:

```
import sys
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass()
message = sys.argv[1]

cipher = encrypt(password, message)
encoded_cipher = b64encode(cipher)
print(encoded_cipher)
```

Queria saber se dá para limitar o tamanho da messagem. Ou criar um próprio metodo de crypt que limita o tamanho da mensagem gerada.

Comment: É isso que vc quer saber? -> https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29989

Comment: Na verdade não, meu encoded_cipher já espero ser maior que o id, porém quero sempre um tamanho fixo. Tipo tamanho máximo do id será sempre 8, e o tamanho do meu encoded_cipher sempre será 20, independente se o id é 1 ou 12345678

Comment: Mas lendo a resposta do cara, entendi algumas coisas que preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer um tamanho fixo de mensagem, você tem que inverter a lógica: basta definir como tamanho a maior resposta possível, e então completar as que forem menores com algum caracter qualquer.

No caso da utilização do `base64`, o caracter usado para preencher é o igual `=` pois ele é ignorado e não faz diferença na hora de decodificar.

Por exemplo, se você quer que suas mensagens tenham todas `TAMANHO` caracteres:

```
if len(encoded_cipher) > TAMANHO:
    raise Exception('Mensagem muito grande, nao cabe')
if len(encoded_cipher) < TAMANHO:
    # completa a mensagem
    encoded_cipher += '=' * (TAMANHO - len(encoded_cipher))
```